# Что делает std::remove_reference_t?

Tags: c++

Применяю `std::remove_reference_t` для выделения памяти под тип указателя, т.е.:

```
p = new remove_reference_t <decltype (*p)> [10];
```

Этот способ мне подсказали, но я не разобрался как работает `remove_reference_t`. Есть ли какие-то "подводные камни" о которых мне следовало бы знать?

Comment: Убирает из типа ссылки. Например, из `int&` делает `int`.

Comment: А чем хуже `p = new std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(p)>[10]`?

Comment: @int3: Для "голого" указателя - ничем не хуже. Для некого "обобщенного" указателя могу быть тонкости.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если `p` имеет обычный "голый" указательный тип, то никаких подводных камней тут нет.

Особенность тут скорее содержится в `decltype`. Когда `decltype` применено непосредственно к имени переменной (напр. `decltype(p)`), то в результате получается тот тип, с которым эта переменная объявлена. А вот когда `decltype` применено к какому-то более сложному *выражению*, результирующий тип зависит от *категории значения* (value category) этого выражения. Для lvalue аргумента типа `T` получится ссылочный тип `T &`, т.е. lvalue-ссылка.

В этом случае `*p` - как раз lvalue. Ссылочный тип в `new` нас не устраивает, т.е. нам надо превратить тип `T &` обратно в `T`, по каковой причине и приходится применять `std::remove_reference_t`.